# Spam issue regarding security on gmail app

Tags: malware, android, spam, gmail

I have been getting a ton of spam email, so I looked at one of them.
I did not click anything, or download anything. However there was a spammy image with option to click on (as they always do).

Would this infect my device or the app (gmail app)? I am using an android phone. All I did was look at a spam email.

As checks, I ran the play protect from the play store. In addition, I have run several malware detection apps: Malwarebytes,Bitdefender etc. I have also looked at the installed apps and used safe mode just in case. Nothing has turned up, all of these steps show no infections.

My questions: a) is there any other check I should do? b) does just looking at an email cause an infection on the gmail app on android?

Answer (score 1):

> b) does just looking at an email cause an infection on the gmail app on android?

Just laying your eyes at the contents of spam or malicious email is safe.

**Like looking or hovering your mouse over**,

- a picture with a link embedded
- at a malicious attachment
- a plain URL

> a) is there any other check I should do?

There's nothing to do because there was nothing that happened. Don't worry.